# GParted doesn't recognize the unallocated space after my current partition

Tags: linux, partition, gparted

I'm using GParted to resize my partitions on Linux. There is about 5GB of unallocated space following the partition sda5. However, when I right click on sda5 and select 'resize/move', it doesn't show the 5GB of unallocated space. So I can't increase the size of sda5 (can't drag to the right, or increase the number for file size. It shows the 'free space following' the sda5 partition as 0, even though there actually is 5GB of unallocated space. Why can't I expand my partition?

Comment: We'd have to actually see your partition table, a detail you unfortunately left out.

Comment: Hmmm....has this asking user resigned (or deleted their account) from the SE or something?  Their name is greyed out?

Comment: @mdpc It came from Server Fault, they don't have an account here

Comment: oh....I thought if you had one account on any SE site, you had an account on all of them.  My misunderstanding apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Because sda5 is a logical partition, which exists inside an extended partition.  You have to have free space inside the extended partition to grow the logical parittion into, so first expand the extended partition.